# How to construct *array of lists of arrays* when the nested arrays have the same length?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to construct an array of list of arrays but my method breaks down if the arrays inside the list have equal dimensions.

I make a list of lists of arrays
and then I convert that list into an array

```
import numpy as np  

foo = [[np.array([4.        , 0.        , 0.1]), np.array([5.        , 0.        , 0.1])],
       [np.array([6.        , 0.        , 0.5])],
       [],
       [],
       []]
foo = np.array(foo)
foo
```

which results in an array of list of arrays:

```
Out[40]: 
array([list([array([4. , 0. , 0.1]), array([5. , 0. , 0.1])]),
       list([array([6. , 0. , 0.5])]), list([]), list([]), list([])],
      dtype=object)
```

perfect.

Now consider the case where array dimensions are equal:

```
bar = [[np.array([4.        , 0.        , 0.1])],
 [np.array([4.        , 0.        , 0.1])],
 [np.array([4.        , 0.        , 0.1])],
 [np.array([4.        , 0.        , 0.1])],
 [np.array([4.        , 0.        , 0.1])]]
bar = np.array(bar)
print(bar)
```

The same method results in merely nested arrays.

```
Out[1]: 
array([[[4.        , 0.        , 0.1]],
       [[4.        , 0.        , 0.1]],
       [[4.        , 0.        , 0.1]],
       [[4.        , 0.        , 0.1]],
       [[4.        , 0.        , 0.1]]])
```

Is there a way to make `bar` an array of list of arrays?

(I would like to have this format because I am appending more arrays to the individual lists)

Comment: "(I would like to have this format because I am appending more arrays to the individual lists)" Why is your outer container an array? What advantage does that give you?

Comment: You are right, there seems to be no advantage. My code works as a list of lists of arrays. I can't recall why I changed it to array. Thanks!

Comment: In general, `dtype=object` is a red flag that you might not want an array.

Comment: If you want to append arrays to the lists like me, would it matter in terms of speed whether the outer wrapper is a list or array? Which would be faster?

Comment: you can time this yourself. I would guess the difference would be minimal, with a `list` being marginally faster if you are going to use a for-loop.